# Searchable dropdown is not working properly when I am using other libraries of jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2, dropdown

I am using searchable dropdown in one of my dropdown list as it contains a lot of data. But its not working and showing error in console as "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function".

Links

```
<link href="../css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../css/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="../js/jquery.select2.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<script>
// Initialize select2
 $("#userList").select2();
</script>
```

HTML
I am using Struts tag in my page. The code is below

```
<div>
<label>User List<label> <br />

<s:select name="user" class="form-control" id="userList" list="userList"
    headerKey="Select User" headerValue="Select User" listKey="emailId" 
    listValue="businessName" autocomplete="off" />
</div>
```

Searchable Dropdown should work properly. Please keep in mind I am using other libraries of jQuery as well.

Comment: Can you provide your markup as well?

Comment: You are not include jquery library only select2.js ?

Comment: I edited my code please check once @Krishna Prashatt

Comment: You dont have an element with `id=userList`?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet?

Comment: @Krishna Prashatt I changed the id now still I am getting error in console is "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).select2 is not a function"

Comment: It seems to me `select2.js` reference is not correct. Can you please check specified path whether file exists or not ?

Comment: @Arshad, The file path is correct because its working on other pages with the same reference path only in this page I am getting error. I am using other jQuery library as "jQuery Multidate calender" is they are conflicting each other.